# Use of !! and quasiquation in select and mutate calls in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

Why do I need to use both `!!` and `as.symbol` inside of the `case_when` call, but not in the `select` function?

```
mtcars
column_name = 'disp'
mtcars_small = mtcars %>%  
    dplyr::select(mpg, !!(column_name)) %>% #!!(column_name) - this is called 'unquoting
    mutate(comparison_condition = case_when(!!as.symbol(column_name) > 300  ~ 'big', #here we need as symbol due to the logic of case_when
                                            !!as.symbol(column_name) < 100 ~ 'small',
                                            TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

Comment: Not a full answer as such but I think it is to do with the object type each `...` section is expecting/evaluating. `select` accepts "<tidy-select> One or more unquoted expressions", whilst `case_when` accepts "A sequence of two-sided formulas". So each is parsed slightly differently.